# JQuery/JS function not firing on <a>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, anchor

I have five slide shows on one page and I want to be able to cycle through all of them. The slideshow is made of an UL with each a different ID, so I want to create two functions for the arrows to cycle through the slides. And I want to pass the slide ID. My code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var slides = document.querySelectorAll('#slides li');
  var slidesTotal = $('#slides li').length;
  var currentSlide = 1;

  function nextSlide() {
    //$('a.nextSlideArrow').click(function() {
        $('#slides .slide' + currentSlide).hide();
        currentSlide++;
        if(currentSlide > slidesTotal) {
          currentSlide = 1;
        }
        $('#slides .slide' + currentSlide).show();
        //return false;
    //});
  }

  function previousSlide() {
    //$('a.previousSlideArrow').click(function() {
      $('#slides .slide' + currentSlide).hide();
      currentSlide--;
      if(currentSlide == 0) {
        currentSlide = slidesTotal;
      }
      $('#slides .slide' + currentSlide).show();
      //return false;
    //});
  }
});

<div id="slider-container">

      <ul id="slides">
        <?php
          for ($i = 1; $i <= $amountImagesSlideshow[3]; $i++) {
            echo '<li class="slide'.$i.'"><img src="'.$directories[3],$i.'.jpg" /></li>';
          }
        ?>
      </ul>

      <div class="galleryPreviewArrows">
         <a href="javascript: previousSlide()" class="previousSlideArrow">&#10094;</a>
         <a href="javascript: nextSlide()" class="nextSlideArrow">&#10095;</a>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Now the funny thing is, if I remove the comments where the click is on the jQuery object and comment out the function, it will work. But not this way? I don't understand.

Comment: `nextSlide` and `previousSlide` is not in the global scope. It is not accessible by HTML elements. Also, since you are using jQuery, handling events is pretty easy. Just follow this guide : https://learn.jquery.com/events/handling-events/

Comment: $( "p" ).on( "click", function() {
    console.log( "<p> was clicked" );
});

So how would I go about making my own function, in which I can pass parameters? Or would I have to make a separate function like this, for every UL slide? That would be 5 almost identical functions. Seems overkill!

Comment: Make use of data attribute on your html. You can then fetch it with `$(this).data('your-name')` and you attribute would look like this : `data-your-name="your value"`

Answer (score 1):

**There is a difference between onclick event and functionality of href attribute.**

When you write like this:

```
<a href="javascript: previousSlide()" class="previousSlideArrow">&#10094;</a>
```

It means, you are hyper referencing(trying to redirect) to some location whenever this anchor tag is clicked.
It doesn't mean you are doing only click action. It means, you are doing click + redirection.
**href = click + redirection.**

whereas, your need is only click event handling. Therefore, how you are handling through jquery.

```
$('a').on("click",function(){
----
----
})
```

This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using href to try to access a javascript function. That attribute is for navigation purposes. Also, binding to a jquery click even is the better way to handle your events so you adhere to separation of concerns design patterns.

If you need to put your function call in an attribute decorator, use the `onclick` attribute instead and don't evaluate the function by adding the parenthesis, just reference it.

```
<a onclick="previousSlide" class="previousSlideArrow">&#10094;</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Anchor tag  is for navigation which requires Href attribute. You should not use href for event handling. Instead:

```
<div class="galleryPreviewArrows">
         <a href="" onclick="previousSlide()" class="previousSlideArrow">&#10094;</a>
         <a href="" onclick="nextSlide()" class="nextSlideArrow">&#10095;</a>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is strange..But writing that function `outside document.ready` works. It looks like that function should be defined before `document` is ready.
That may be the reson `alert` works always..which is a built-in function.

Also this is not the recommended way to bind event listner. Use jquery `on/off` to add/remove listners.

```js
  function nextSlide() {
    //$('a.nextSlideArrow').click(function() {
    alert('next');
    //return false;
    //});
  }

  function previousSlide() {
    //$('a.previousSlideArrow').click(function() {
    alert('prev');
    //return false;
    //});
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="slider-container">
  <div class="galleryPreviewArrows">
    <a href="javascript: previousSlide()" class="previousSlideArrow">&#10094;</a>
    <a href="javascript: nextSlide()" class="nextSlideArrow">&#10095;</a>
  </div>

</div>
```